# VHDL 8-bit unsigned counter overflow detection

Tags: overflow, vhdl, counter, unsigned

i am trying to create an 8-bit unsigned counter which count-step depends on the 3-bit control input. The problem is that the RST, control, addition, subtraction and underflow works correctly but overflow doesn't work at all. On the test bench when i get an overflow the overflow value itself doesn't seem to change from '0' to '1' as it should, but it just starts counting from the start.

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Counter is
    Port ( Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Control : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           Count : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Overflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Underflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Valid : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Counter;

architecture Behavioral of Counter is
    signal tmpCount : UNSIGNED(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal tmpOverflow : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal tmpUnderflow : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal tmpValid : STD_LOGIC := '1'; 

begin

    process 
    begin
    

    wait until Clk'EVENT and Clk = '1';
    
    
    if tmpOverflow='1' or tmpUnderflow='1' or RST='1' then
        if RST='1' then 
            tmpCount<=(others=>'0');
            tmpOverflow<='0';
            tmpUnderflow<='0';
            tmpValid<='1';
        end if;
        
        else 
            if Control="000" then
                tmpCount<= tmpCount - 5;
            elsif Control="001" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount - 2;
            elsif Control="011" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount + 1;
            elsif Control="100" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount + 2;
            elsif Control="101" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount + 5;
            elsif Control="110" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount + 6;
            elsif Control="111" then
                tmpCount<=tmpCount + 29;
        end if;
                
        if tmpCount > 255 then
            tmpOverflow <= '1';
        elsif tmpCount < 0 then
            tmpUnderflow <= '1';
        end if;

        end if;
        
        if tmpUnderflow='1' or tmpOverflow='1' then
            tmpValid<='0';
            tmpCount<= (others =>'U');
        end if;

    
    end process;
    
    Count<=std_logic_vector(tmpCount);
    Overflow<=tmpOverflow;
    Underflow<=tmpUnderflow;
    Valid<=tmpValid;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Overflow occurs in two's complement (signed) binary numbers (not unsigned, which can rollover). Note that tmpCount > 255 should never be TRUE for signal tmpCount : UNSIGNED(7 downto 0) which has a binary numerical range of 0 to 255. Provide a [mcve] along with a specific problem.

Comment: Overflow occurs in both signed and unsigned numbers. Wikipedia's "Integer Overflow" article has a nice picture of an (unsigned) odometer overflowing from 99999.9 to 0.0.

Comment: The indentation of your code is very strange; the first `else` should be indented as the first `if`, you should probably fix that.

Comment: There are several issues with your code (not mentioning the indentation). 1. You declare `tmpCount` as `unsigned`, so it cannot be less than 0 and your `elsif tmpCount < 0 then` test will never pass. 2. You declare it as 8 bits long, so it cannot be larger than 255 and your `if tmpCount > 255 then` test will never pass. 3. You apparently think that VHDL signals are assigned instantaneously, like variables in most programming languages. They are not and you should probably read a VHDL book before coding anything in this programming language.